# Vertical dropdown menu not appearing next to parent li

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I am trying to  make a vertical dropdown menu. When the li element is hovered over, then display the dropdown menu directly next to the li element (on the right).

This is my current CSS:

```
div.menu div.navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 0;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul ul li {
    background: #1b2133;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul li a {
    color: #e4ebf7;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 18px 30px;
    display: block;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul li a:hover {
    background: #0c1224;
}

div.menu div.navigation ul li a i {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

div.right-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    display: table;
}
```

However, whenever I hover over an element the dropdown menu displays at the top of the navigation menu:
[image: Dropdown Menu Screenshot]

I have tried setting top: 0; but then the dropdown menu appears 1 li below the parent li.

Cheers!

EDIT: As requested, here's the HTML code that I'm using (obviously this is still a work in progress).

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dashboard</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url(); ?>upgrade.php">Updates</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Media Library</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Media Library</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Users</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">All Users</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Create New Profile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>Appearance</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Theme Editor</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i>Plugins</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Installed Plugins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Install A Plugin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>Settings</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Permalinks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right-container">
            <p>Hi</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: It will be good, if you can post the HTML of this code. It would make easy to help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Absolute positioning takes the closest positioned ancestor as reference point. In your code, that seems to be the outer UL. If you want the parent LI to be the reference point, then you need to position that, at least relative.

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own css using your HTML. May be this could help.

It has the exact same thing that you want.

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dashboard</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_admin_url(); ?>upgrade.php">Updates</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Media Library</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Media Library</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upload</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Users</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">All Users</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Your Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Create New Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i>Appearance</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Theme Editor</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plug" aria-hidden="true"></i>Plugins</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Installed Plugins</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Install A Plugin</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>Settings</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reading</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Permalinks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navigation ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .navigation ul li {
            position: relative;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #0c1224;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .navigation ul ul {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            left: 82%;
            top: -2%;
        }
        .navigation ul li:hover > ul {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .navigation ul li:hover {
            background-color: #1b2133;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .navigation ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
        }
```